# Manipulate hidden columns

Tags: modern-experience, hidden

Using SPO Modern, I've hidden certain columns on a list on the newitem.aspx pg as I do not want users to be able to manipulate them. However as an admin I need to be able to access the columns; is there any way of doing so without having to edit the item in grid view? In previous version of sharepoint i'd insert some simple jquery in a CEWP webpart but that doesnt seem to be an option in SPO.

Answer (score 1):

You can select the context menu for the column and select **Edit conditional formula** to enter a formula that will determine if the column should be displayed on the form.

[image: Edit columns panel]

In that formula, you can use `@me` to get the email address of the current user. So you can set the conditional formula to show the column to you but not to other users. Something like this:

`=if(@me == 'rob@robwindsortest986.onmicrosoft.com', 'true', 'false')`

[image: Conditional formula dialog]

I'm not sure if there's a way to get additional information about the current user (e.g. if they are a site admin). I did some searching but I didn't find anything. Maybe someone else can provide more information on this.

Comment: thanks for this! Do you know if there's a way I can designate others via they email address? not just me

Comment: @Jerome Yes, you can nest the if statements to designate multiple users. For example, `=if(@me == 'rob@robwindsortest986.onmicrosoft.com', 'true', if(@me == 'AdeleV@robwindsortest986.onmicrosoft.com', 'true', 'false')`

Comment: Thanks, I used the formula with my own address; the columns are hidden but it's hidden to me too, not sure why. Are there any other unique identifiers that can be used other than email? say login ID?

Comment: @Jerome What formula did you use (you can strip out the email addresses)? Maybe it's not formatted correctly. As to the second part of your question, I'm not sure if there's a way to get additional information about the current user. I did some searching but I didn't find anything.

Comment: my apologies, i thought true meant SHOW, and false was HIDE...these are the formulas that I used,  I haven't tested the form with other users yet but do they look correct? can I use either?
=if(@me == 'jerome.westmaas@cibc.com', 'false', 'true') 
OR 
=if([$jerome.westmaas@cibc.com]==@me, 'false', 'true')
The idea is the columns are visible to me but hidden for others.

Comment: The first has the correct form but the `true` and `false` are reversed. The `if` function takes three parameters, a condition, the value to return if the condition is true, an the value to return if the condition is false. In the context of conditional formatting of columns in forms, the column will show if the formula returns true and it will not show if the formula returns false. So, if you want the column to show for `jerome.westmaas@cibc.com` but not for others, the formula should be `=if(@me == 'jerome.westmaas@cibc.com', 'true', 'false')`

Comment: Appreciate it but the formula is still not working; when I apply =if(@me == 'jerome.westmaas@cibc.com', 'true', 'false') it's hiding the columns for me and others too. To be clear I'm trying to hide the columns in newform.aspx. Is there something i'm missing? :(

Comment: found this on the microsoft site...

Unsupported column types in conditional formulas:

While the formula supports many of the available column types, we do not currently support the following column types:

Person or Group with multiple selections
Choice with multiple selections
Time calculations in Date and Time column
Currency columns
Location columns
Calculated columns
Managed Metadata columns